# date.now() comparison returning NaN

Tags: javascript

I wrote the following timing function but the `timer = currentTime - startTime;` keeps giving me `NaN`

```
var timer = 0;
var currentTime = 0;
var trialTime = 5;

window.onload = function() {
    setInterval(addtime,10);
};

function addtime() {
    if (timer == 0) {
        var startTime = Date.now();
    }
    currentTime = Date.now();
    timer = currentTime - startTime;

    if (timer >= (trialTime*1000)) {
        timer = 0;
        $("form").submit();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what is going wrong because when I add code to show me the values of `startTime` and `currentTime` they display as numbers but when I try to show `timer` it only gives me `NaN` and therefore the if statement never evaluates as `TRUE`.  Not sure what is going wrong here but I'm running out of ideas on how to get this working.

Comment: If you are only going to do something after 5 seconds, why are you checking every 0.01 seconds? That's 49 checks that are guaranteed to fail and so are not worth doing.

Comment: I need a close to ms accuracy timer because I have other functions relying on the timer that are recording when certain user interactions are happening.

Comment: Using setInterval to measure time will result in very poor accuracy. Many browsers pretend to have 1ms accuracy but they don't. IE doesn't even pretend, its clock ticks at about 15ms (maybe faster in newer versions).

Answer (score 2):

Move your startTime declaration outside of your if

```
var startTime;
if (timer == 0) {
    startTime = Date.now();
}
```

Comment: `startTime` will still be `undefined` if `timer` is not 0.

Comment: Really? 2 votes for something that makes absolutely no difference at all?

Answer (score 2):

```
if (timer == 0) {
    var startTime = Date.now();
}
```

`startTime` is defined only when `timer` is `0`. You have to define `startTime` outside the `addTime` function too.

But by your code, it looks like you just want to delay a form submission.

Just use `setTimeout`, it will be much simple and clean.

```
var trialTime = 5;

window.onload = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
         $("form").submit();
    }, trialTime * 1000);
};
```

Comment: setInterval fires again and again in intervals, while setTimeout only fires once.

Comment: I'm actually doing a lot more within the timer function than submitting the form but got rid of that code to focus on the timer not working.

Comment: Stictly, startTime is always defined, but it is **assigned a value** only when timer is `0`.

Comment: @RobG Yep, that's strict, here i say `is defined` means `not undefined` :)

Answer (score 0):

Note that *setInterval* doesn't run at exactly the specified interval, it only runs as soon as it can after the interval. Consequently, it will drift and subsequent calls may or may not occur at the moments you expect.

Consider using a pattern like the following:

```
window.onload = (function() {

    // Keep these variables in closures so not global but still
    // accessible to function called by setInterval
    var timer = 0;
    var currentTime = 0;
    var trialTime = 5;
    var regKey;
    var startTime;

    function addtime() {
      if (timer == 0) {
        startTime = Date.now();
      }
      currentTime = Date.now();
      timer = currentTime - startTime;

      if (timer >= (trialTime * 1000)) {
        timer = 0;
        console.log('done');

        // Cancel the timer when you're finished with it
        clearInterval(regKey);

        // Do whatever else

      }
    }

    return function() {
      // Keep a timer reference so it can be cancelled
      regKey = setInterval(addtime, 10);
    };
}());
```

I still don't understand why the timer is called every 10ms but doesn't do anything for **at least** 5 seconds. On my machine, this takes about 20 seconds to finish.